# Using case to create multiple columns of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query in MS SQL 2005 that will return data for 4 date ranges as separate columns in my results set.

Right now my query looks like the query below. It works fine, however I want to add the additional columns for each date range since it currently supports one date range when.

This would then return a total1,total2, total3 and total 4 column instead of a single total column like the current query below. Each total would represent the 4 date ranges:

I am fairly sure this can be accomplished using case statements, but am not 100%.

Any help would be certainly appreciated.

```
 SELECT  
       vendor,location,
      sum(ExtPrice) as total 

  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]
where processdate between '2010-11-03' and '2010-12-14'

and location <>''
and vendor <> ''

group by vendor,location with rollup
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
 SELECT  
       vendor,location,
      sum(CASE WHEN processdate BETWEEN @date1start AND @date1end THEN xtPrice ELSE 0 END) as total,
      sum(CASE WHEN processdate BETWEEN @date2start AND @date2end THEN xtPrice ELSE 0 END) as total2, 
      sum(CASE WHEN processdate BETWEEN @date3start AND @date3end THEN xtPrice ELSE 0 END) as total3, 
      sum(CASE WHEN processdate BETWEEN @date4start AND @date4end THEN xtPrice ELSE 0 END) as total4     
  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]

and location <>''
and vendor <> ''

group by vendor,location with rollup
```

And you can change the `WHEN` portion to make your desired date ranges.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot this works well. I am also trying the approach below for this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Subqueries, ie

```
select sd.vendor, sd.location, sd1.total, sd2.total, sd3.total, sd4.total
from (select distinct vendor, location from saledata) AS sd
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT vendor,location, sum(ExtPrice) as total 
  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]
where processdate between 'startdate1' and 'enddate1'
and location <>''
and vendor <> ''
group by vendor,location with rollup) sd1 on sd1.vendor=sd.vendor and sd1.location=sd.location

LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT vendor,location, sum(ExtPrice) as total 
  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]
where processdate between 'startdate2' and 'enddate2'
and location <>''
and vendor <> ''
group by vendor,location with rollup) sd2 on sd2.vendor=sd.vendor and sd2.location=sd.location

LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT vendor,location, sum(ExtPrice) as total 
  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]
where processdate between 'startdate3' and 'enddate3'
and location <>''
and vendor <> ''
group by vendor,location with rollup) sd3 on sd3.vendor=sd.vendor and sd3.location=sd.location

LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT vendor,location, sum(ExtPrice) as total 
  FROM [database].[dbo].[saledata]
where processdate between 'startdate4' and 'enddate4'
and location <>''
and vendor <> ''
group by vendor,location with rollup) sd4 on sd4.vendor=sd.vendor and sd4.location=sd.location
```

Comment: Can I make the null value returned  be 0? I tried the isnull but it doesn't seem to force to 0

Comment: @joe -- I believe the cost to run this query is more than my query.  No offense, @SteveCav.  joe, try to run both queries in a query analyzer and see the running time and cost of each to compare.

Comment: I think you are right about the query cost. I just realized that I need to pull data from an older database if its below a certain date, which doesn't allow me to use your query in its current state.

Comment: yeah, I totally agree that Beemer's is the better solution. I rushed it.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to use your solution Steve  because I need to change the database for specific date ranges. What's the best way of changing the null to 0 with your code?

Comment: Are you using isnull in the subquery or main query? It should be in the top level select, ie select sd.vendor, sd.location, isnull(sd1.total,0) AS FirstRangeTotal...